# Is there any case that the coefficient of variable of interest in DiD more significant when adding more variables?

Tags: econometrics

Considering a Difference-in-Differences equation with a dummy variable:

$$
y_i = \alpha + \beta D_i + Xit + \varepsilon_i.
$$
While $$Xit$$
is a set of covariates.
Today **when I add more covariates, the p-value decrease**. Is it normal?

And if it is a problem, what should I deal with that?

Comment: It can happen if $D$ and $X$ are not much correlated each other and X is important for explaining $y$, when X decreases the variance of the (remaining) error and the variability in D is not much affected by partialing out X, resulting in a reduced standard error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let me tell you that it is bad statistics to compare $p$-values across different specification. What you certainly should not do is to pick the specification based on the $p$-values that you obtain.

Having said this. Assume that the right specification is given by:
$$
y_i = \alpha + \beta D_i + \gamma X_{i} + \varepsilon_i 
$$
Assume you wrongly estimate:
$$
y_i = \alpha + \beta D_i + \delta_i
$$
where now $\delta_i = \varepsilon_i + \gamma X_i$ captures both the random error $\varepsilon_i$ and the effect of $X_i$.

If you would estimate the second specification, you actually identify the following:
$$
\begin{align*}
\hat \beta &= \mathbb{E}(y_i|D_i = 1) - \mathbb{E}(y_i|D_i = 0),\\
&= \beta + \mathbb{E}(\delta_i|D_i = 1) - \mathbb{E}(\delta_i|D_i = 0),\\
&= \beta + \gamma\left[\mathbb{E}(X_i|D_i = 1) - \mathbb{E}(X_i|D_i = 0)\right]
\end{align*}
$$
Depending on the second term, $\hat \beta$ might be lower or higher than $\beta$. This will depend on the sign of $\gamma$ and the direction of correlation between $X_i$ and $D_i$. For example if $\gamma > 0$ and $D_i = 1$ is associated with higher values of $X_i$ then $\hat \beta > \beta$, so you will tend to overestimate the effect of $D_i$ on $y_i$ (as you are also capturing part of the effect of $X_i$ in your estimate).

Whether you should include $X_i$ or not into the regression is not something that can be answered using statistics alone. If $X_i$ captures confounders (i.e. something that affects both $y_i$ and $D_i$), then yes you should add it as you otherwise do not capture the causal effect of $D_i$ on $y_i$ but also part of the effect of $X_i$ on $y_i$.

Answer (score 2):

When you add covariates, $\beta$ is interpreted as "the effect of $D$ on $y$ holding fixed $X$. Adding variables to $X$ can either increase or decrease the p-value depending on the relationship of $X, D,$ and $y$.